# How to find the previous X records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with an int id, they are sorted, but not necessarily sequential.

So... 1,5,10,11,12,13, etc.

If I want to find the next 10 records starting at 11, then that's easy, I just do:

```
select * from myTable where id >= 11 limit 10
```

If I want to find the previous 10 records starting at 11, then right now I've got:

```
select * from myTable where id < 11 order by id desc limit 10
```

this gives me what I want, but it's in reverse order (as expected given the query). I know it's easy to reverse a list, but just wanted to see if there was any cool trick where I can avoid having to reverse the list?

Comment: Just put it in a subquery: `select * from (your query) order by id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id < 11 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
) AS sub
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**